# prev pointer not working for my stack using GList

Tags: c++, stack, glib

I'm implementing a stack using GList (doubly) but when I assign my stack with the last element using `g_list_last(*stack*)` the program doesn't print my stack at all

Pointing to the first element using `g_list_first(*stack*)` works and I can traverse with stack->next pointer

Here's my test program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <glib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        cout << "Enter the no of random data to push: ";
        int number = 0;
        cin >> number;

        GList *stack = nullptr;
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                int data = random() % 10;
                stack = g_list_append(stack, GINT_TO_POINTER(data));
                cout << "Push: " << data << endl;
        }

        cout << "Printing the stack forward:\n";
        stack = g_list_first(stack);
        while (stack != nullptr) {
                cout << GPOINTER_TO_INT(stack->data);
                cout << "->";
                stack = stack->next;
        }
        cout << "nullptr" << endl;

        cout << "Printing the stack backward:\n";
        stack = g_list_last(stack);
        while (stack != NULL) {
                cout << GPOINTER_TO_INT(stack->data);
                cout << "->";
                stack = stack->prev;
        }
        cout << "nullptr" << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Do I have to manually assign the prev link while appending?

Comment: I don't know much about glist, but I suspect, that you are invoking undefined behavior, due to passing uninitialized pointer to `g_list_append`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Just assigned nullptr to my stack and tested it now. No, the issue still persists :(

Comment: Undefined behavior doesn't mean that it will always break the behavior. It may also, appear to work in the way you expected it to. So, after said fix, you, most likely have one issue with your code, opposed to two.

Comment: Updating the code :) to avoid the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would not recommend using GLib in a C++ code base; GLib is a C library, full of idiomatic C code and functionality. I'd suggest using the C++ standard library, instead.

[`GList`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html) is a doubly linked list where each element is composed by three pointers:

```cpp
typedef struct _GList GList;
struct _GList
{
  void *data; // untyped pointer data
  GList *prev; // pointer to the previous element in the list
  GList *next; // pointer to the next element in the list
}
```

For convenience, all the `GList` functions accept a `NULL` as a valid list; in the case of `g_list_append()`, passing a `NULL` list as the first argument means that it will allocate a new `GList` element for the data you're passing and place it at the start of the list.

In your code you're taking the head of the list after populating it, and calling `g_list_first()`, which is a no-op on the head of the list; then you proceed to consume it by iterating over it, until you hit the end of the list, where you assign `nullptr` to the `stack` variable. Since `nullptr`/`NULL` is a valid empty `GList`, you're now calling `g_list_last()` on a valid, but empty list, which will return `NULL`, and thus prevent you from iterating backwards. Additionally, you're now leaking the memory allocated to the list.

The solution is to *never* iterate a `GList` with the same variable that holds the head of the list:

```cpp
        cout << "Printing the stack forward:\n";
        GList *iter = g_list_first(stack);
        while (iter != nullptr) {
                cout << GPOINTER_TO_INT(iter->data);
                cout << "->";
                iter = iter->next;
        }
        cout << "nullptr" << endl;
```

The code above will consume the `iter` variable, instead of the `stack`. Which means that the code below:

```cpp
        cout << "Printing the stack backward:\n";
        iter = g_list_last(stack);
        while (iter != NULL) {
                cout << GPOINTER_TO_INT(iter->data);
                cout << "->";
                iter = iter->prev;
        }
        cout << "nullptr" << endl;
```

will work appropriately, and walk the stack backwards, as the `stack` variable still points to the head of the list, and you're now consuming a temporary iterator.

Remember to call `g_list_free()` on the list to release any resources allocated for it—and `g_list_free_full()` in case you're allocating the contents of the `data` pointer as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution + more insights into GLib and my code leaking memory :)